# Pointer being freed was not allocated, but looks like it was

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having issues with the destructor of my class in this code. It is saying that is was never allocated, however it should have been, and I never delete it myself. Here is snippets of the code:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING_CONSTRUCTORS
//Test Constructors
cout << "Test constructors \nConctructor 1:\n";
Doctor testDoc1;
testDoc1.displayPatientArray();
cout << "\nConstructor 2:\n";
Doctor testDoc2(2);
testDoc2.displayPatientArray();
cout << "\nConstructor 3:\n";
//Implement more test cases below:
Doctor testDoc3("Wesley Cates");
testDoc3.displayPatientArray();
cout << "\nConstructor 4:\n";
Doctor testDoc4("Baylor Bishop", 3);
testDoc4.displayPatientArray();
#endif


Doctor::Doctor() : doctorName("need a name."), patientArraySize(100), numOfPatient(0) {
//Create a dynamic array for patients below:
//stringPtr_t* pArray;
stringPtr_t* patientArray;
patientArray = new stringPtr_t[patientArraySize];
```

And the class:

```
typedef unsigned short ushort_t;
typedef string* stringPtr_t;
class Doctor {
private:
string doctorName;
stringPtr_t patientArray;
ushort_t patientArraySize;
ushort_t numOfPatient;
public:
Doctor();
Doctor(ushort_t patientArrayCapacity);
Doctor(string docName);
Doctor(string docName, ushort_t patientArrayCapacity);
bool addPatient(string patientName);

void displayPatientArray();
void resizePatientArray(ushort_t newArraySize);

string getDoctorName() const {return doctorName;}
ushort_t getNumOfPatient() const {return numOfPatient;}
ushort_t getArraySize() const {return patientArraySize;}

void setDoctorName(string docName) {doctorName.assign(docName);};
void emptyPatientArray() {numOfPatient = 0;}

Doctor& operator =(const Doctor& docSource);
~Doctor() {delete [] patientArray;}
};
```

Comment: Do you have a problem of indentation and writing readable code?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone can help you if you don't provide a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It may not be the problem yet, but you'll probably be wanting a copy constructor as well (C++ rule of three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you are initialising in your constructor `Doctor::Doctor()` is a *local* variable called 'patientArray', not the class variable that you are then deleting in the destructor.

To fix the problem, change the constructor to this:

`Doctor::Doctor() : doctorName("need a name."), patientArraySize(100), numOfPatient(0) {
// Create a dynamic array for patients below:
// stringPtr_t* pArray;
// Delete local variable declaration that was here: stringPtr_t* patientArray;
//
patientArray = new string[patientArraySize];`

Comment: It is telling me that I must do *new instead of new. When I do this it causes the same error. Am I missing something else?

Comment: patientArray = new string[patientArraySize];

Answer (score 0):

You are using `typedef string* stringPtr_t;`.  So stringPtr_t variable is already pointer.

So no need to use `stringPtr_t* patientArray;` You can just use `stringPtr_t patientArray;`

In case if you are using  `stringPtr_t* patientArray;`, **patientArray** is *string*** and you need only *string **

Comment: Although this is true, it's not the proximal cause of the error he is seeing.

Comment: You are right, but that's not the problem. The class member `patientArray` is correctly declared based on the typedef as is. It's the local variable declaration in the constructor that incorrectly becomes a pointer to a pointer, however, that declaration shouldn't be there in the first place.